# Using StreamTokenizer to read a structured file

Tags: java, tokenize

If I have a file with some structure to it:

```
type
2
0 0 name
100 100 name
1
1 2 name name
```

How can I use a `StreamTokenizer` to process this file? Is the only way the procedural approach?

i.e.

```
StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader(filename));

if (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    st.nextToken();
    if (st.sval == "typea") {
        st.nextToken();

        int i = (int) st.nval;
        if (i > 0) {
            while (i > 0) {
                // process node sets
            }
        }
    } else if (st.sval == "typeb") {
        st.nextToken();

        int i = (int) st.nval;
        if (i > 0) {
            while (i > 0) {
                // process node sets
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's fine to skip if unexpected tokens exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to do it in a procedural fashion. Consider breaking things into separate functions and gathering your node sets as you go along. Here's something simple that parses your given example. You can build on it as things get more complicated. I'm sure someone else can offer you something better.

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import static java.io.StreamTokenizer.*;


public class NodeToker {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
      final String fname = "/data/types.txt";
      InputStream stream = Class.class.getResourceAsStream(fname);

      if (stream == null) {
         System.err.println("Could not open stream " + fname);
      } else {
         NodeToker typeToker = new NodeToker();
         AllTypes allTypes = typeToker.parse(stream);

         try { stream.close(); }
         catch (IOException ex) { }

         Formatter fmtr = new Formatter(System.out);

         int groupCount = 0;
         for (NodeSet nodeSet : allTypes) {
            groupCount++;
            int nodeCount = 0;
            for (Node node : nodeSet) {
               fmtr.format("Set %s, Node %s: %s%n",
                       groupCount, ++nodeCount, node);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public AllTypes parse(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
      Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

      StreamTokenizer tok = new StreamTokenizer(reader);
      setupToker(tok);

      AllTypes allTypes = new AllTypes();

      while (tok.nextToken() != TT_EOF) {
         String text = tok.sval == null ? "" : tok.sval;

         if (text.startsWith("type")) {
            // slurp newline
            tok.nextToken();
            handleNodeSet(tok, allTypes);
         }
      }

      return allTypes;
   }

   private void handleNodeSet(
           StreamTokenizer tok,
           AllTypes allTypes) throws IOException {
      while (tok.nextToken() != TT_EOF) {
         if (tok.ttype == TT_NUMBER) {
            final int numRows = (int) tok.nval;
            tok.nextToken();

            NodeSet nodeSet = allTypes.newNodeSet();

            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
               Node node = nodeSet.newNode();
               handleNode(tok, node);
            }
         } else {
            // maybe beginning of next type?
            tok.pushBack();
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   private void handleNode(StreamTokenizer tok,
           Node node) throws IOException {
      while (!endOfRow(tok)) {
         if (tok.ttype == TT_NUMBER) {
            node.addNumber((int)tok.nval);
         } else if (tok.ttype == TT_WORD) {
            node.addName(tok.sval);
         }
      }
   }

   private void setupToker(StreamTokenizer tok) {
      tok.eolIsSignificant(true);
   }

   private boolean endOfRow(StreamTokenizer tok) throws IOException {
      return (tok.nextToken() == TT_EOL) || (tok.ttype == TT_EOF);
   }

   public static class AllTypes implements Iterable<NodeSet> {
      private List<NodeSet> typesList = new ArrayList<NodeSet>();

      public NodeSet newNodeSet() {
         NodeSet typeGroup = new NodeSet();
         typesList.add(typeGroup);
         return typeGroup;
      }

      public Iterator<NodeSet> iterator() {
         return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(typesList).iterator();
      }

   }

   public static class NodeSet implements Iterable<Node> {
      private List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();

      public Node newNode() {
         Node node = new Node();
         nodeList.add(node);
         return node;
      }

      public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
         return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(nodeList).iterator();
      }

   }

   public static class Node {
      private List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      private List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

      public void addName(String name) {
         names.add(name);
      }

      public void addNumber(int number) {
         numbers.add(number);
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Node{" + "numbers=" + numbers + " names=" + names + '}';
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A great deal of the functionality of `StreamTokenizer` has been replaced by the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class, I believe it's worth looking before proceeding.

Comment: locked into use of the `StreamTokenizer` :(