# Java scanner class reading tab delimited strings from text file

Tags: java

I am a student learning Java coding. 
I am trying to check a username and password within a text file. If the text file contains the username, then the 3 next fields are assigned to variables.

The text file has 4 tab-delimited fields and 5 unique lines.

If I enter the username and password from the first line of a text file, then I can get boolean values to return true. If I enter any other username or password the boolean values remain false. I use a print method and can tell that the while loop iterates thru the entire file.

I'm trying to figure out why the other lines of the text files aren't being compared to the username or password variables.

My code:

```
while (inFS.hasNext() && !userGood && !passGood) {
    credString = inFS.next();
    System.out.println(credString);

    if (userName.equals(credString)) {
        userGood = true;
        System.out.println("*****userGood TRUE");
        encryptedPass = inFS.next();
        unencryptedPass = inFS.next();
        userRole = inFS.next();
        if (sb.toString().equals(encryptedPass)){
            passGood = true;
            System.out.println("*****passGood TRUE");
            break;
      }                                                           
 }
```

}

Comment: why don't you read one line at a time using `nextLine` ?

Comment: Please, attach an example of your text file.

Comment: There are already several related answered question. Two of them I found at once:  [Reading Structured File in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393560/reading-structured-file-in-java), [Using StreamTokenizer to read a structured file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780319/using-streamtokenizer-to-read-a-structured-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the next() method does not skip a line, so you should make a nextLine() call before going to the next while iteration.

Comment: the line changed to 
credString = inFS.nextLine().split("\t");
then i used the credstring array to compare elements of each line to the user and password.  Thanks for help.